# NSArray containsObject NSString Not Working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

I hava an array list (RatingsList) containing below contents

```
<CFArray 0x910e1a0 [0x2952380]>{type = mutable-small, count = 8, values = (
    0 : <CFString 0x910e0d0 [0x2952380]>{contents = "NR-Adult"}
    1 : <CFString 0x910e0f0 [0x2952380]>{contents = "NC-17/TV-MA"}
    2 : <CFString 0x910e110 [0x2952380]>{contents = "R"}
    3 : <CFString 0x910e120 [0x2952380]>{contents = "PG-13/TV-14"}
    4 : <CFString 0x910e140 [0x2952380]>{contents = "PG/TV-PG"}
    5 : <CFString 0x910e160 [0x2952380]>{contents = "G/TV-G"}
    6 : <CFString 0x910e170 [0x2952380]>{contents = "TV-Y/TV-Y7"}
    7 : <CFString 0x910e190 [0x2952380]>{contents = "NR"}
```

we are comparing for PG-13

```
[RatingsList containsObject:@"PG-13"]
```

return false.

Answer (score 12):

Of course it returns false. Your array doesn't contain "PG-13", although it does contain "PG-13/TV-14".

Answer (score 9):

Use a simple NSPredicate.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains %@", aString];
NSArray *filteredArray = [RatingsList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
if ([filteredArray count] > 0) return YES;
return NO;
```